# Separable regular Hausdorff spaces have a basis of cardinality $\le 2^{\aleph_0}$? Why is $[0,1]^A$ separable iff $|A| \le 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: general-topology

I have a couple of questions:

1. I need a hint to show that if X is a regular, Hausdorff and separable space, then there exists a basis $B$ of the topology of X such that $|B|\le 2^{\aleph_0}$.
2. How do you show that $[0,1]^{A}$ is separable if and only if $|A|\le 2^{\aleph_0}$

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

(1) First show that since $X$ is regular and Hausdorff, it has a base of regular open sets, i.e., open sets $U$ such that $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}U=U$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{U\subseteq X:\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}U=U\}$, and let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. Show that if $U\in\mathscr{B}$, then $U=\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(U\cap D)$. Use this to show that there is an injection (one-to-one function) from $\mathscr{B}$ into $\wp(D)$, and conclude that $|\mathscr{B}|\le|\wp(D)|$.

(2) One direction of this is a special case of the [Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem](http://planetmath.org/hewittmarczewskipondiczerytheorem); Hewitt’s original paper can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1946-52-08/S0002-9904-1946-08613-9/). This result itself is [Theorem $16.4$c](http://books.google.com/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Willard’s *General Topology*; it is also proved [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2010;task=show_msg;msg=0487.0001) at Ask a Topologist by [Henno Brandsma](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4280/henno-brandsma).